# how to add if function in declare array php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, foreach

hello I have a problem here, I want to create an if statement inside the array declaration in php like this

```
foreach($data as $d){
$temparray = [
                if($d['STAT'] =='STUND'){
                    'stat_acc' => $stat_stund_acc,
                    'stat_blok' => $stat_stund_blok
                 }else{
                    'stat_acc' => $stat_acc,
                    'stat_blok' => $stat_blok
                 }
                 'other_data1' => $other_data1
                 'other_data2' => $other_data2

            ];
}
```

but in my vscode there is a warning error

Comment: This is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as @rafalrozek said with a general `if` guarding the whole thing, or you can guard only want you want:

```php
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $temparray = [
        'other_data1' => $other_data1,
        'other_data2' => $other_data2,
    ];

    if ($d['STAT'] == 'STUND') {
        $temparray['stat_acc'] = $stat_stund_acc;
        $temparray['stat_blok'] = $stat_stund_blok;
    } else {
        $temparray['stat_acc'] = $stat_acc;
        $temparray['stat_blok'] = $stat_blok;
    }
}
```

Also, as long as the conditional check isn't too expensive, you can use a ternary:

```php
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $temparray = [
        'stat_acc' => $d['STAT'] == 'STUND' ? $stat_stund_acc : $stat_acc,
        'stat_blok' => $d['STAT'] == 'STUND' ? $stat_stund_blok : $stat_blok,
        'other_data1' => $other_data1,
        'other_data2' => $other_data2,
    ];
}
```

Comment: what I need is tenary code, I forgot the basics of programming, thank you very much sir, the best solution for my case is in your second way

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this?

```
$temparray = [];
if($d['STAT'] =='STUND'){
    $temparray = [
        'stat_acc' => $stat_stund_acc,
        'stat_blok' => $stat_stund_blok,
        'other_data1' => $other_data1,
        'other_data2' => $other_data2
    ];
}
else{
    $temparray = [
        'stat_acc' => $stat_acc,
         'stat_blok' => $stat_blok,
        'other_data1' => $other_data1,
        'other_data2' => $other_data2
    ];
}
```

Comment: hi thankyou rafarozek, in my case there are 3 pieces of data that need an if statment, and if it is declared one then it needs at least 6 if and that extends my code